# VBA identify column header of highlighted cells

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA. I'm using an excel sheet with dropdowns selected by a user in cells A10:E10. My macro runs data validation on the information inputted by the user. If data entered does not fit parameters set by the macro, the cell is highlighted. At the end of the macro I would like a MsgBox stating that highlighted cells exist in x column/s. Here is what I have:

```
Sub CheckErrors()
Range("A11:E100000").Select
Dim high As Range
Dim c As Range
Set high = Selection
  For Each c In high
    If c.Interior.Pattern <> xlNone Then
     MsgBox ("Please update highlighted cells in  " & c.Column & " and run Data Validation again")
    Exit Sub
   End If
  Next c
 MsgBox ("Data verification is complete")

End Sub
```

Instead of saying c.Column I would ideally like the code to identify which cells are highlighted and display the column header in A10:E10. For instance, if B24 and C82 are highlighted I would like the MsgBox to state "Please update highlighted cells found in Phone Numbers and Addresses". "Phone Numbers" and "Addresses" would be the values in cells B10 and C10 respectively and would come from a dropdown list that the user previously selected.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy!  You've already done most of the work by getting the column, all you need to do is insert your value with the appropriate row and you've got it.  Here is what your message box line should look like:

```
 `MsgBox ("Please update hilighted cells in " & Cells(10, c.Column).value & " and run Data Validation again")`
```

I'm not sure how familiar you are with cells, but it is Cells(row index, column index) and using the .Value property returns the contents of that cell.  Assuming that your headers are in the 10th row of your workbook, this should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, and I appreciate the explaination on Cells. Is it possible for the MsgBox to include multiple column headers (if applicable)?

Comment: Sure, you can concantenate as many values into the message box as you might like.  You'll just have to set them up and insert them in such a way that the final message makes sense.  I'd maybe recommend looping through all the cells in your worksheet and add the cells to a collection, it's a really, really handy object.  I'd be careful though, if you have multiple cells across columns it might just end up rattling off the header of every column, which might be less useful to your user than hilighting cells and providing column headers one at a time.